# Magento 2: Add product to guest cart programmatically

Tags: addtocart, magento2.2

Please let me know how to add product to cart programmatically using an event observer in `magento 2.2`

Comment: on which event, you want to add product in cart ?

Comment: I need help in adding product to cart programmatically, we can consider `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view` event.

Comment: When cart page is loaded or when user goes to view cart.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to add product into cart

```
public function __construct(
    /* Add below dependencies */
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartModel
) {
    $this->cartModel = $cartModel;
}

// Add below code in your function
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
if ($product->getId() && $product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
    try {
        $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['qty' => 1]);
        $this->cartModel->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $request);
        $this->cartModel->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //echo $e->getMessage(); die;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the comment for code block that need to add in your function